# How to extract part of ID feature from one column in R

Tags: r, export-to-csv, data-extraction, data-processing

I've got data with around 10,000 rows like this:

```
HH_ID         DEMAND
201101010000  35090
201101010030  35612
201101010100  35245
201101010130  34161
201101010200  33156
201101010230  32556
...           ...
```

where HH_ID refers to the half hourly ID, e.g 201101010230 refers to Year2011, Data0101, and time 0230.

I would like extract the Year and Date from HH_ID, and to have the data like:

```
HH_ID         Year_ID  Date_ID    DEMAND
201101010000    2011    0101       35090
201101010030    2011    0101       35612
201101010100    2011    0101       35245
201101010130    2011    0101       34161
...           ...
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html. This is a good start to learn about the data time manipulations

Comment: Thanks that will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `substring`

```
Year_ID <- substring(df1$HH_ID, 1, 4)
Date_ID <-  substring(df1$HH_ID, 5, 8)
cbind(df1[1], Year_ID, Date_ID, df1[2])
#         HH_ID Year_ID Date_ID DEMAND
#1 201101010000    2011    0101  35090
#2 201101010030    2011    0101  35612
#3 201101010100    2011    0101  35245
#4 201101010130    2011    0101  34161
#5 201101010200    2011    0101  33156
#6 201101010230    2011    0101  32556
```

---

Or another option is `sub` with `read.table`

```
cbind(df1, read.csv(text=sub("(.{4})(.{4}).*", "\\1,\\2", df1$HH_ID), 
  col.names = c("Year_ID", "Date_ID"), 
   colClasses = c("numeric", "character"), header=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

I second akrun's solution with `substring` and `strtrim` (though substring will work for both)

```
mydata$Year_ID<-strtrim(mydata$HH_ID, 4)
mydata$ Date_ID<-substr(mydata$HH_ID, 5,8)
mydata<-mydata[,c(1,3,4,2)]
mydata

       HH_ID Year_ID Date_ID DEMAND
201101010000    2011    0101  35090
201101010030    2011    0101  35612
201101010100    2011    0101  35245
201101010130    2011    0101  34161
201101010200    2011    0101  33156
201101010230    2011    0101  32556
```

However I cannot reproduce your issue with file size.

```
for(i in 1:11){
  mydata<-rbind(mydata, mydata)
  }
nrow(mydata)
[1] 12288 #larger that your indicated 10000 rows.

write.csv(mydata,'New_Demand.csv',row.names = F)
file.size('New_demand.csv')/1000 
[1] 417.8 # in Kilobytes.
```

Comment: I just found that I made a very stupid mistake when exporting data, thanks anyway.